# Nuxt.js - For each route a different transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, transition, nuxt.js

I'm currently working with Nuxt.js, which is awesome! I made some transitions for each page I created. However I want to call a specific transition when you go to a page from an archive. For example:

In an archive you have two a hrefs, each a href goes to another page. So you have different routes like: archive -> page 1 and archive -> page 2. I want to make an transition-out for the archive when it's leaving to page 1 and page 2. I need to call a specific transition for each route. But I couldn't find anything in documentation how this works. Has someone an idea or an example?

Comment: Nuxt is build on top of Vue.js right? Can't you wrap your route into a normal vue transition and dynamically name it depending on your route?
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I can't figure it out how to change the transition name on each route...

It has to be something with this function: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition#function

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.

Essentially, you just want to call in the transition key as a function. Think of the 'from' as the archive page and the 'to' as the next page.  You could do something like this:

```
transition (to, from) {
  if (to.path === '/page-1'){
      return 'transition-one' 
  } else if (to.path === '/page-2') {
      return 'transition-two'
  }
}
```

Or in pseudo code...

```
// If the 'to' path is the same as /path-1
    // Do the transition with the name 'transition-one'
// Otherwise, if the 'to' path is the same as /path-2
    // Do the transition with the name 'transition-two'.
```

You can put this transition function in your module exports, just the same as your lifecycle hooks.  Does this help a bit?

Comment: Thanks! It's not working for me,  it does make sense though. But it's still calls the standard 'page' transition instead of 'transition-one' or 'transition-two'.

Comment: Whats are 'transition-one' and 'transition-two'? CSS classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you using layout, it's enough insert `<transition>` between `<nuxt/>`.
please refer [vue official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

> templete

```
 <v-content>
  <transition name="fade">
    <nuxt />
  </transition>
</v-content>
```

> css

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
```